# Error message: Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint Decision.java : 183, reason : the breakpoint is set out of any class

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, compilation

I have recently started using NetBeans 11.2 IDE. I am using JDK8 because my project supports JDK 8.

1. Suddenly I am not able to attach debugger in my project. An error message is shown:

> the breakpoint is set out of any class.

2. Code assistance is disabled on my NetBeans IDE. It doesn't suggest anything while writing code anymore, also it didn't give compilation error if anything wrong has been written;
3. A lock file gets generated when I start the IDE

I have these 3 questions, could you please help me out with this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please be aware that you cannot set a breakpoint in a code row that is not executable.

Comment: Hi , yes I have set breakpoint in a code row which is executable. But still it gives that error.

Comment: Then, it will help if you post a screenshot or code on where the breakpoint is set

Comment: I am working on virtual machine and we are not allowed to send screenshots or click pictures from mobile. As it is a finance project, there are some rules and policies set